# Method missing error when using cucumber (with rails, webrat, and mongomapper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, mongomapper, webrat

I'm writing a few basic step instructions in Cucumber, and can't figure out why it's throwing up a "method missing" error. Here's the precise error:

```
undefined method `question' for nil:NilClass (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

The root of this error is this line from my index.html.erb page:

```
<p id="question"><%= @question.question %></p>
```

So it looks like the test thinks that @question is nil. I'm not sure why it thinks this. What should I change in my step instructions? Here they are:

```
Given /^a question$/ do
  @question = Question.create!(:question => "here's my question..", :answer => "right_answer", :num => "1")
end

When /^I answer the question$/ do
  visit root_path
  fill_in "Answer", :with => "Wrong answer"
  click_button "Submit answer"
end
```

The first step instruction passes, but the second does not.

---

EDIT: Here's my entire index.html.erb page, in case it's useful:

```
<% title "Questions" %>

<p id="question"><%= @question.question %></p>

<%= form_for @user_answer do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :answer %></div>
  <div><%= f.text_field :answer %></div>
  <div id="sign_up_button"><%= f.submit "Submit answer" %></div>
<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "New Question", new_question_path %></p>
```

---

EDIT: My Question model, in case it's useful:

```
class Question
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :question, String, :required => true
  key :answer, String, :required => true
  key :num, String, :required => true
```

Comment: Are you setting @question in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're giving us the excerpt from the stack trace properly, your issue is that you aren't setting @question properly in your controller - which you have not posted above. Several other people have alluded to that in their answers, but I'm quite convinced of it.

Your tests - cucumber or otherwise - have nothing to do with the problem you're having.

I suspect that if you visit your root_url, you will get the same problem - you will get a stack trace and an error. Without knowing exactly what your routes are, I can't be sure where you're being sent when you visit the root_url.

Your controller *should* be loading up @question with your question object (probably via Question.find() or something like it), then rendering your index.html.erb page. So your 'index' action in your controller ought to be the thing that is filling in your @question.

Note that you're not following rest-ey principles here - usually people have 'indexes' give you lists of things (questions in your instance), then id's give you a particular question.

I bet if you go to a particular question it works fine.

Maybe your problem is that you shouldn't be testing by visiting 'root_path' in the first place? Maybe you should be going to a particular "question's" path?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any validations at Question model? Maybe you can't create new question object like you trying.

Comment: I do have validations (see edited question above), but I believe my Question.create! meets all those validations. But maybe I'm misunderstanding/missing something.

Comment: Ok, I just thought that u forget about validations. Unfortunately now I have no clue what is going wrong :/